# Calculating Tie Plate loading and double shear

Tags: wood, structural, engineering

I am considering the use of L strap ties from Strong Tie. I will be connecting two 4x4's in an L-configuration. The image at the very bottom-right corner of the below PDF illustrates exactly the configuration I will use.

http://www.strongtie.com/ftp/catalogs/c-c-2015/C-C-2015-p194.pdf

The lower 4x4 will be vertical and the upper 4x4 will be cantilevered from the top of the vertical 4x4, exactly as in the illustration.

The PDF states that the hangers:

> are to be installed in pairs with machine bolts in double shear. A
>   single part with machine bolts in single shear is not load-rated.

1. What does "installed in pairs" mean? I assume this means that there will be one tie on each side of the 4x4s?
2. What does "in double shear" mean in this context?

I will be supporting a 96-inch long shelf with 1200lbs of evenly distributed dead load. There will be a set of 4x4s and L-ties spaced every 24 inches under the shelf, for a total of four, meaning each 4x4 and L-tie configuration will be supporting 1200/4 = 300lbs. If the L-ties are used in pairs, each tie will be loaded at 150lbs.

3. Do I meet the allowable loading for the L-ties? Is this considered "tension", "uplift" or "F1" per the PDF document?